# How do I calculate $(1+i)^{3-4i}$ in normal form $z = x + iy$ and in the exponential representation $ z =\left | z \right |\exp (i \arg (z))$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I calculate $(1+i)^{3-4i}$ in normal form $z = x + iy$ and in the exponential representation $ z =\left | z \right |\exp (i \arg (z))$?

$z=(1+i)=\sqrt(2)e^{arctan(1)}$

$(1+i)^{3-4i}=z^{3-4i}$

But that is $(\sqrt(2)e^{arctan(1)})^{3-4i}$. 
How do i simplify this expression?

Comment: Use power function

Comment: $arctan1=\pi/4$ and so essentially you have an e-power raised to a complex number, say $e^{a+bi}$ and so this can be split into $e^a$ which is just real and $e^{bi}$ for which you can use CIS

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute the logarithms of $1+i$; note that
$$
1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}
$$
so the logarithms of $1+i$ are
$$
\frac{1}{2}\log2+\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\right)i
$$
for $k$ any integer.

Therefore the determinations of $(1+i)^{3-4i}$ are
$$
\exp\left((3-4i)\left(\frac{1}{2}\log2+\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\right)i\right)\right)
$$
I leave the final computations to you. The value for $k=0$ is called the *principal value*.